# mongoEngine miss the filed when the value is null after save

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine, flask-mongoengine

Here is a sample document:

```
{"id":1,
"info":{"age":10,"grade":80,"address":"LA"}
}
```

What I did:

```
# query the document
student = Student.objects(id=1).first()
# change the info
student.info['address'] = None
# save the change
studen.save()
```

When I look at the db, this document miss the address field. the info is {"age":10,"grade":80}
Why save() operation can auto miss the null field, how to avoid it?
(I know use update can keep the null field, but can I use save and still keep the null field?)

Answer (score 0):

You can either try to give it `Nan` or void string `""`

```
student.info = {"age":10,"grade":80,"address":""}
```

or

```
student.info = {"age":10,"grade":80,"address":Nan}
```

Comment: So there is not a good way to keep the value of address to be None?

Comment: @McCreeFeng , no in Python we use Nan instead